# ImportError: No module named <appname>

Tags: python, django

A lot of other people have come across the error `No module named <appname>`. However. I couldn't relate to the problem they had. I tried to run manage.py shell and then imported the app (blog). It worked. So what is wrong in my code?

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'projectname.blog.views.index', name = 'index')
]
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from blog.models import posts

def home(request):
    return render('index.html', {'title': 'My First Post'})
```

**Error message:**

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     1.8.5
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named blog

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
```

Comment: Your project is not a package (and it shouldn't be). Leave just `blog.views.index`.

Comment: Thanks @sobolevn. But then it gives me the error: 'Could not import 'blog.views.index'. View does not exist in module blog.views.'

Comment: Your view name is `home`. not `index`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Your project is not a package, so you shouldn't be adding `projectname`
2. Your view name is `home`, not `index`

Therefore, you should be using:

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your project name in path to specific app. Instead of

```
url(r'^$', 'projectname.blog.views.index', name = 'index')
```

use

```
url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index', name = 'index')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py you were defined the home instead of index 
Try below one

```
def index(request):
    return render('index.html', {'title': 'My First Post'})
```